# Send HTTP request in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to connect to a server without typing "http://". I have to get only the server name and port number from the user. With this, I should be able to connect to a particular server...

Answer (score 5):

In its simplest form, it looks something like this:

```
- (void)loadHostName:(NSString *)hostName onPort:(NSInteger)portNumber {

    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@:%i", hostName, portNumber]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection release];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Oh noes! %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    [responseData release];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    // Do something with the data, like load it in a web view.
    [webView loadData:responseData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
    [responseData release];
}
```

In production code, you should handle cache requests, authentication challenges etc. (see the messages on NSURLConnection), but the above example will send an HTTP request and load it into a web view.

Comment: @Richard Setting your ivars to nil when you're done with them is always a good thing to do, but I left it out to keep the example focused on the question. Autoreleasing it is meaningless.

Comment: The `responseData` variable is accessed for the last time in either `connectionDidFinishLoading:` or `connection:didFailWithError:` depending on the outcome of the request. There are no more NSURLConnection callbacks, so nothing will access the variable again, and setting it to nil will not gain you anything. Same thing for autorelasing it. It just means that the autorelease pool will release it later, instead of you doing it now. In both cases you're done with the variable, so you might as well keep your memory management as tight as possible. Just don't release it in `dealloc` also.

Comment: you're not addressing the case I'm talking about. This isn't productive. Deleting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
  NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@:%i", hostName, portNumber]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:aUrl
                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                     timeoutInterval:60.0];


   NSURLResponse *resp = nil;
   NSError *err = nil;
   NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: theRequest             returningResponse: &resp error: &err];
NSString * theString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
[resp release];
[err release];
NSLog(@"response: %@", theString);
```

Comment: Synchronous requests are bad because:

1. They block the run loop, so if they're called on the main thread, the UI is locked while waiting for the response.
2. You can't cancel a synchronous request.
3. You can't respond to authentication challenges.
4. You can't validate SSL certificate errors.
5. ...
Please don't use synchronous requests, even though they require less code.

Answer (score 0):

well you can hardcode HTTP:// with the server name

example

```
NSString *serverName = "stackoverflow.com";
NSNumber *portNumber = 10;
NSString *finalYrl  = [NSString StringWithFormat:@"HTTP://%@:%@",serverName , portNumber];
```